# Why $\mathbb{S}^0$ has a symplectic structure?

Tags: symplectic-geometry

There's an excercise problem in Heckman's symplectic geometry book that says $\mathbb{S}^n$ is a symplectic manifold iff $n=0$ or $n=2$, but I don't see the structure over $\mathbb{S}^0$.

Comment: $\mathbb{S}^0$ is two isolated points, whose tangent bundles are 0-dimensional. Any 0-dimensional space has a unique symplectic structure (the zero bilinear form). Having said that it seems like a silly special case.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks

Comment: Here's a curiosity about the existence of symplectic forms in [products of spheres](https://mathoverflow.net/q/304908/54656).